# Pagination with JPA and Oracle database

Tags: oracle, jpa

This week i was looking into a sorting issue in a WebApp. Sorting a table in the browser by a selected column did not work properly. It turned out that in the application, we used JPAs `CriteriaQuery` to create the query and then create a `TypedQuery` for the pagination as follows:

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<SomeEntity> q = cb.createQuery(SomeEntity.class);
Root<SomeEntity> c = q.from(SomeEntity.class);
q.select(c);
...
q.orderBy(cb.asc(c.get("SomeColumn")));
TypedQuery<> query = em.createQuery(q);
query.setFirstResult(pageIx * pageSize);
query.setMaxResults(pageSize);
...
```

This is pretty much how the documentation suggests to create queries ([see here](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjrij.html)).

In the logs i saw that this generates an SQL query like this:

```
select * from (
    select lots_of_columns from some_view order by selected_column
) where rownum <= 50
```

Since Oralce 10 the ordering of the enclosed select has no effect according to the documentation and, if i remember correctly, this also makes sense according to relational algebra. We use Oracle 12c.

So my question is, how am i supposed to takle this correctly? 
I have found that `offset` and `fetch` should be used but i couldn't find how to tell JPA to generate the SQL accordingly. Also i have found a post that suggested to add the id to the order by clause, however this did not solve the problem either.

Thank you in advance for any thoughts and hints on the topic.

Comment: What documentation told you "the ordering of the enclosed select has no effect according to the documentation"?  I don't believe that is correct.  Is the problem with the first page of the data?  Or subsequent pages?  I'd be interested to see what SQL was generated for subsequent pages.

Comment: i found it here: https://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.3.0/ref/rrefsqlj13658.html
And the problem was on the first page, i havent checked on the subsequent pages...

Comment: That's documentation for JavaDB, a different database engine that happens to also be owned by Oracle Corp.  If you run the query you posted against Oracle directly, do you get the data you expect?